# executing linux programs repeatedly through multi-user webpages without crashing

Tags: php, jquery, c++, linux, web-applications

I'm working on a hardware project that (currently) uses the Beaglebone Black (eventually custom hardware will be used), and am attempting to set up a webpage on its web server that returns the status of all four leds, live, in a loop. And I want this webpage to be able to be accessed by multiple people simultaneously.

I've got the webpage updating the values of the leds live, but the problem is that if two instances of the webpage are open, they start to behave weird and eventually crash.

The webpage uses a jquery timer that executes every 10ms.

```
<script>
        var Timer=setInterval(function(){GetLed()}, 10);

        function GetLed()
        {
            $("#div1").load("getled3.php");

        }
</script>
```

getled3.php uses php to execute 4 linux commands (but these might eventually be C++ programs in the future as we expand the capability of the webpage), and prints the results:

```
<?php 

exec("cat /sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0/brightness", $Led0);
exec("cat /sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr1/brightness", $Led1);
exec("cat /sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr2/brightness", $Led2);
exec("cat /sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr3/brightness", $Led3);

print($Led0[0] . ", " . $Led1[0] . ", " . $Led2[0] . ", " . $Led3[0]);

?>
```

I'm willing to do my own research into how to create a web application that plays nicely with multiple users, but so far, my searches haven't turned up any useful results, which could just be my wording.

If anyone could just post some links that would point me in the right direction for creating a web application that controls hardware, that would be most helpful, as the eventual implementation will be extremely complex, and might include the hardware running a "master" application on a loop, with the web page providing the user the ability to alter hardware set up.

I guess the best example of something like what we're doing would be a dynamic router set up page.

Thanks in advance. I'm going to keep searching in the meantime.

---

Edit:  (with responses to comments)

I was looking to see if there was a standard way of doing this, or at least a best-practice. The end product will eventually allow the user to change settings on the hardware, force the hardware to send information to other hardware, read information about the hardware and other hardware attached to the beaglebone black. It'll eventually get quite expansive, and so what I really need is a resource (perhaps a book) where I can read about how this sort of thing is usually done.

The whole thing will eventually incorporate PWMs, GPIOs, ADCs, etc.

As for the method of accessing the leds, I understand "exec cat" isn't the best way to get that information.

I have since changed the entire set up so that now, when the beaglebone black boots, it loads a c++ program that runs in a loop, and writes files with hardware information.

Then, the webpage calls that were originally running "exec cat" are now just loading the program's output file into the browser. This solved the crashing problem, but just doesn't feel like the correct method of doing this project, because there would be a ton of files with information in them about the ADC values, the PWM values, etc. To further convolute things, the file accesses would really need a mutex to prevent the c++ program from writing a file while the web program was reading it, and a mutex to prevent the web program from reading a file if the c++ program were currently writing it. That would make 3 files per process.

Comment: i don't want to be smartass but you should do this professionally my company uses Nagios. Nagios checks alot of things on servers or even you can write your own sh, python, php in cli and nagios frequently trigger it and it can mail you the result.

Comment: why `exec` `cat`? All that does is print out a file's contents. You could just as easily use `file_get_contents()` without having to fire up a shell + cat

Comment: Have you verified that it isn't just a problem with concurrent access to the same LED?

Comment: @ molbdnilo:The problem is that the web-server is a linux user and when you have multiple instances of the web-page, it's as if a single user is attempting to run multiple programs simultaneously from the command line, which linux does not approve of.

Comment: also, see edits to original post above.

Answer (score 0):

A way can be to build a shell script that sets a local variable with the leds states. Then you put this script as a cron job (that is launched every 10ms or whatever you want).

After you only need to obtain the value of the local variable.